# ¿Como obtener la fecha menor de un valor registrado mayor a 0 en sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente query:

```
SELECT fecha, SUM(pendientes) AS saldo,referencia,nombre,rut FROM 
( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(pedidos.fecha,'%d/%m/%Y') AS fecha,pedidos.fecha AS fecha2,
(pedidos.total - IFNULL((SELECT SUM(valor) FROM pagosd WHERE numerodoc=pedidos.numerodoc AND tipodoc=pedidos.tipodoc),0)) AS pendientes, 
clientes.referencia,clientes.nombre,CAST(CONCAT(clientes.rut, '-', clientes.dv) AS CHAR(11)) AS rut 
FROM pedidos LEFT JOIN clientes ON clientes.telefono=pedidos.telefono WHERE pedidos.registro > 0 
AND clientes.referencia>0 AND pedidos.tipodoc = 11  ORDER BY pedidos.fecha ASC ) AS clientesdeudores 
GROUP BY referencia
```

Donde me muestra lo siguientes registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hago una sumatoria de saldo, todo está bien, excepto la fecha, ya que no trae la primera fecha de la deuda. Lo que marque con rojo en la imagen fecha, indica que no es la correcta. Porque al ejecutar la siguiente subquery (una parte del codigo de arriba de sql):

```
( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(pedidos.fecha,'%d/%m/%Y') AS fecha,pedidos.fecha AS fecha2,
(pedidos.total - IFNULL((SELECT SUM(valor) FROM pagosd WHERE numerodoc=pedidos.numerodoc AND tipodoc=pedidos.tipodoc),0)) AS pendientes, 
clientes.referencia,clientes.nombre,CAST(CONCAT(clientes.rut, '-', clientes.dv) AS CHAR(11)) AS rut 
FROM pedidos LEFT JOIN clientes ON clientes.telefono=pedidos.telefono WHERE pedidos.registro > 0 
AND clientes.referencia>0 AND pedidos.tipodoc = 11  ORDER BY pedidos.fecha ASC )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta ultima imagen, me mostra la fecha de donde comienza a tener saldo, la cual quiero que esa sea la a mostrar.

La idea es poder mostrar en la primera query, la fecha desde donde empieza a tener saldo mayor a 0.

Alguna idea, sería algo como esto:

```
SELECT fecha, SUM(pendientes) AS saldo,referencia,nombre,rut,MIN(fecha2), CASE
    WHEN SUM(pendientes) > 0  THEN **(subquery que obtiene la fecha minima)**
    ELSE fecha2
END  AS fecha_minima

FROM 
( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(pedidos.fecha,'%d/%m/%Y') AS fecha,pedidos.fecha AS fecha2,
(pedidos.total - IFNULL((SELECT SUM(valor) FROM pagosd WHERE numerodoc=pedidos.numerodoc AND tipodoc=pedidos.tipodoc),0)) AS pendientes, 
clientes.referencia,clientes.nombre,CAST(CONCAT(clientes.rut, '-', clientes.dv) AS CHAR(11)) AS rut 
FROM pedidos LEFT JOIN clientes ON clientes.telefono=pedidos.telefono WHERE pedidos.registro > 0 
AND clientes.referencia>0 AND pedidos.tipodoc = 11  ORDER BY pedidos.fecha ASC ) AS clientesdeudores 
GROUP BY referencia
```

No se si me explique bien. Espero que puedan darme alguna idea o ayuda. Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: Sería cuestión de poner `ORDER BY pedidos.fecha DESC` por fuera, o sea, como parte de la consulta global, no en la parte del JOIN como estás haciendo ahora mismo.

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano por responder, pero toma la menor que sin importar que el saldo sea o no mayor a 0